# List containing images in App Inventor

Tags: listview, app-inventor

Is there anyway that I can create a list that instead of text, contain images, in **App Inventor**?

I want the list to be filled dynamically by the user of the application with the Camera element, not to be prefilled with images by the developer in the Blocks Editor.

To be more specific, I want to create a picture journal.

If it is, can you guys please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this directly using the built-in App Inventor components.
However using additionally an embedded HTML file and some **jQuery Mobile** code, it is possible.

[image]

See more information about this example [here](https://puravidaapps.com/listview.php) and some more App Inventor examples, which also use embedded HTML see [here](https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#html).